# Shutdown causes for macOS

Tags: macos, sleep, shutdown, macos-sierra

After upgrading to Sierra I cannot seem to locate shutdown causes via Console. Has anyone been able to find previous shutdown causes or an alternate option possibly with the command line (e.g. `grep`).

In earlier versions of macOS I could search "Sleep" and "Shutdown" and see their corresponding code.

Examples:

- shutdown cause: 3
- shutdown cause: 5
- sleep cause: -128

Answer (score 1):

I could compose the right command to display the shutdown causes in Sierra:

`log show --predicate 'eventMessage CONTAINS "shutdown cause"'`

Answer (score 0):

The precise meaning of the codes is not publicly documented, although according to [@grgarside's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside) website for [**Shutdown Causes**](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/), the causes for the ones listed in the question are:

- **3**

> **Hard shutdown.** Check power button.

- **5**

> **Correct Shut-Down.** Shutdown was initiated, from the OS X Shut Down menu or other shutdown commands. This normally does not indicate an issue with your system.

- [Shut-Down cause: **-128**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/212809/22781)

  In general, -128 is an unknown hardware problem, but commonly it can be related either to memory issue or to the battery time span (at the end of its useful life).

  - See also: [Tracking down hard shutdown cause—software? hardware? overheat?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/227702/22781)

---

Here are a number of questions related to other shutdown causes:

- [Shut-Down cause: **-60**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/111603/22781)

  > Bad master directory block (badMDBErr).
- [Shut-Down cause: **-62**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/186094/22781)

  > Watchdog timer detected unresponsive application, restarting the system.
- [Shut-Down cause: **-64**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/239264/22781)
- [Shut-Down cause: **-104**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/179648/22781)

  > Possibly linked to a battery issue.
- [Shut-Down cause: **-108**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/69752/22781)

  > Likely memory issue.
- [Shut-Down cause: **-112**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/158235/22781)

  > Restart cause logged when it freezes in a hard manner.

---

For a full up-to-date list, see [Shutdown Causes](https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/shutdown-causes/).

If you've got negative numbers very often, Apple is more keen to get your Mac to the repair, as it usually indicates problem with your hardware.

---

General suggestions in case of further problems:

- [Reset the SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295) and [Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) (which you did).
- Run an [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257).
- [Log a kernel panic](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201753).
- Install [*EtreCheck* app](https://etrecheck.com/) to find serious problems on your Mac.